# Large file upload, 500 server error

Tags: craft3, assets, error, upload, server

We've a Craft 3 site hosted with Digital Ocean (Serverpilot set-up) with the DNS routed through Cloudflare.

The client has experienced issues uploading large ZIP files to (c140MB), returning a 413 error. After updating the PHP conf to enable larger files and tweaked the Nginx conf realised that the issue was with Cloudflare file upload limit.

Having set up a subdomain for the site to bypass Cloudflare we are now getting 500 errors in the browser console when trying to upload large files through the Craft control panel:

```
POST https://admin.site.com/index.php?p=admin/actions/assets/save-asset 500
```

There are no errors in the server logs and nothing showing up in the Craft debug toolbar.

Any suggestions on debugging and resolving this issue or on what might be causing the 500 error?

Comment: You're positive that Cloudflare isn't getting involved on the admin.site.com requests?  I ask because why would you need to increase the Cloudflare file upload limit if it weren't? The 500 ISE has to be originating from _somewhere_.  If it were Craft, it would be in Craft's logs, but I suspect it's coming from something external (nginx, Cloudflare, etc.) and they'll have their own logging mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks Brad - set up subdomain to bypass Cloudflare which is why getting 500 error now rather than the 413 error. Flummoxed why nothing turning up in Craft logs or on server. Is there any way can debug the error from the above POST request that is turning up in the browser console?

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood that part - sorry.  If you check the that request in the network tab, then click the response tab, does it come back with anything?

Comment: Hmmm, seems to be an Nginx error. Will investigate further but strange nothing turning up in logs … 

`<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>`